# where i can edit the broadleaf update asset's html and controller files?

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Oops, I **can't find the broadleaf update asset's html** and controller files in my project? I can write controller but want to do some changes in the html file. How can I do? and where i can find that html for update asset?

Answer (score 0):

All of the HTML templates in the demo site are in site/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates.